# Spring boot mongodb querydsl - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

I'm trying to use Querydsl in my spring boot project but when I try to generate Qclasses it is giving an error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.querydsl.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor

here are my dependencies :

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.7
 

com.example
MyShopify
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
MyShopify
MyShopify demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>16</java.version>

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>16</source>
                <target>16</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Error Log:

```
[ERROR] execute error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report (FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute (AbstractProcessorMojo.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:512)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:691)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:519)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$NameProcessIterator.getNextProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:584)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$NameProcessIterator.hasNext (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:570)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Iterators$CompoundIterator.update (Iterators.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Iterators$CompoundIterator.hasNext (Iterators.java:60)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.hasNext (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:842)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.atLeastOneProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:639)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1141)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:921)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.querydsl.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:433)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:512)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:691)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:519)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$NameProcessIterator.getNextProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:584)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$NameProcessIterator.hasNext (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:570)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Iterators$CompoundIterator.update (Iterators.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Iterators$CompoundIterator.hasNext (Iterators.java:60)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.hasNext (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:842)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.atLeastOneProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:639)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1141)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:921)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:831)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

this question is repeated but you should use queryDSL 4 instead of queryDSL 3 ,
queryDSL 4 is managed by groupId com.querydsl instead of com.mysema.querydsl